# Can we identify button using same x and y co ordinates for iPhone and iPad using Appium?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, appium, appium-android, appium-ios

I want to implement a test feature here I have to click on element based on x and y co ordinates. Rather than using if an else statements for iPhone and iPad is there any way I can use the same x and y co ordinates for both iPhone and iPad.

same goes to android Phone and Tab

Is there any way?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the width and height of the device and can execute the same code for both(iPas & iPhone)

```
Dimension dimens = driver.manage().window().getSize();
double xCoordinate = dimens.getWidth() * 0.5; 
double yCoordinate = dimens.getHeight() * 0.5;
//you may have to cast these values to int
```

Using these values in a tap for example:

```
driver.tap(1, xCoordinate, yCoordinate, 1000);
```

will cause Appium to tap in the middle of the screen using one finger for 1000 milliseconds for all the devices.

Comment: Hi Vaishali,Thank you for your reply. What I am asking is if you want to click / tap a button rom x and y co ordinates, how do ou do the same in iPhone and  iPad using same line of code? Is it possible?

Comment: For that, you can calculate coordinates form your specified X and Y. For taping on X and Y coordinates you should apply the appropriate logic on which you want to tap.

Comment: Sorry it is becoming bit complex to understand. If my iPhoneX has 187 X 406 as x and y coordinates and iPad has 512 X 683, how ca I run same tap function?